# ExtJS 7.0.0-CE ext-charts package is not in sencha.myget.org repo

Tags: npm, charts, extjs7

I'm using ExtJS community edition + open tooling (npm)

Framework and additional sencha modules are distributed through their npm repo at https://sencha.myget.org/ and so far everything worked as it should.

But if I try to use `Ext.chart`  I found oun that this is a separate package. As stated in [sencha's docs](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/7.0.0-CE/guides/using_systems/using_npm/extjs_packages.html) `ext-charts` package should be alongside other pkgs i.e `ext-modern-theme-material`, which is working just fine, but ext-charts is not there!

I get 404 ERR on `npm install @sencha/ext-charts` and can't find it on repo's web page.

Could someone point me to package location or some other tips regarding ext-charts installation?

Answer (score 1):

Chart is for Premium users in ExtJS 7.0 [modern toolkit](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/7.0.0/modern/Ext.chart.CartesianChart.html). However, it is free in [classic toolkit](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/7.0.0/classic/Ext.chart.CartesianChart.html). So you need to build in classic toolkit to get charts.